# How can you query 2 levels of connections between people in one MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a MySQL table with the following schema:

```
+---------+---------+----------------------+------------+
| User ID | Song ID | Recommending User ID | Created On |
+---------+---------+----------------------+------------+
|  1001   |   54    |        1004          | 2011-07-21 |
|  1002   |   23    |        1005          | 2011-07-28 |
|  1002   |   166   |        1001          | 2011-07-31 |
+---------+---------+----------------------+------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is give users points when someone favorites a song that they recommend. So the query takes every user in the system and finds out who has the most points in relation to the user its scanning.

So, say we take user 1001. 1001 favorited song id 54 that was recommended by 1004 on 7/21. The query needs to give 40 points when scanning 1001.

Now what makes this complicated is that I want to add a second level. So for each user that 1001 favorited (i.e. 1004) I want to search them (1004) the same way giving anyone 1004 favorited 20 points when still computing 1001.

Just to clarify once more. Let's take 1002 as an example:

```
Computing 1002:
    User 1005 gets 40 pts
    User 1001 gets 40 pts
    Computing 1005
         nothing
    Computing 1001
         User 1004 gets 20 pts
Done
```

Any help on how to start is greatly appreciated :)

*Edit: specified mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (I'm calling the table you outlined above "Recommendations"):

Each time a song is marked "favorite," we need to look whether someone else recommended that. So suppose user `UserID` just marked `SongID` as his "favorite." The following person gets 40 points:

```
SELECT Recommending_user_id
FROM Recommendations 
WHERE User_id = [UserID] 
AND Song_id = [SongID]
```

What you asked is how to check for another level of recommendations. We can do it by a `JOIN` of the Recommendations table to itself:

```
SELECT Forty.Recommending_user_id, Twenty.Recommending_user_id
FROM Recommendations Forty
LEFT JOIN Recommendations Twenty
       ON (Forty.Recommending_user_id = Twenty.User_id
       AND Forty.Song_id = Twenty.Song_id)
WHERE Forty.User_id = [UserID] 
  AND Forty.Song_id = [SongID]
```

The `LEFT JOIN` makes sure that if the 20-point user doesn't exist, it doesn't break the query; you'll just get `NULL` for Twenty.Recommending_user_id.

Note that you could join again to give 10 points to the third level up, if you wanted. :)

Comment: would this require me to iterate it over each combination of UserID and SongID though? I could probably throw this into a subquery where UserID and SongID are joined against a parent that has the combinations. That could be pretty slow though I feel.

Comment: I guess calculating all the scores from scratch every time might be slow, but maybe not. To get around that, instead keep a column "points" for each user, and update it whenever someone "favorites" or "defavorites" a song by adding or subtracting 40 or 20. Worst-case you only have to run the huge query once at the start to get everyone's initial points. You could even run the huge query occasionally to make sure you have the points exactly right (I think this is how SO reputation works!).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways, but I only have 5 minutes before I go see my lady friend.  So, here's one possible way...
*(No she's not a blow up)*

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Mode = 1 THEN [principle].recommending_user_id ELSE [secondary].recommending_user_id END AS user_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mode = 1 THEN 40 ELSE 20 END) AS Score
FROM
  myTable   AS [principle]
LEFT JOIN
  myTable   AS [secondary]
    ON [principle].recommending_user_id = [secondary].user_id
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS MODE UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS Mode
WHERE
  CASE WHEN Mode = 1 THEN [principle].recommending_user_id ELSE [secondary].recommending_user_id END IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN Mode = 1 THEN [principle].recommending_user_id ELSE [secondary].recommending_user_id END
```

Comment: Thanks Dems, I've started testing this but it's giving me incredible inflated numbers. I'll keep tweaking it and see if I'm doing something wrong.